# Not able to store class name of my Kotlin data class in Redis cache when using the JsonJackson Codec

Tags: json, kotlin, redis, reddison

When storing a java object as json, `@class` will be added to data and that will be used to DEserialize in to the respective object.

But when a `Kotlin` data class is involved, it is not adding the `@class` and when I try to deserialize ,I am getting the error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Missing type id when trying to resolve subtype of [simple type, class java.lang.Object]: missing type id property '@class'
 at [Source: (byte[])"{"Integer":1}"; line: 1, column: 13]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException.from(InvalidTypeIdException.java:43)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.missingTypeIdException(DeserializationContext.java:1771)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext.java:1300)
```

I cannot add the annotation `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS)` as this would expose my data class and I understand that the error is because Kotlin data classes are final by default.

Is there any solution to overcome this error?